# Can't connect my external HDD to my PC

Tags: hard-drive, external-hdd

It's been quite a while that I am trying to connect my external HDD to my PC (this HDD is only for media content).
I don't want to mount this HDD to my PC, I just want to view the content that has been stored in the HDD. I have been seeing other question but non of them helping me with my situation and this is error message showing every time I connect my HDD to my PC:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/mubasher/LG External HDD Drive: 
Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/mubasher/LG External HDD Drive"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Comment: The answer is in your question: mount the volume read-only with the 'ro' mount option.

Comment: i don't know how to do that. That is the only problem

Comment: See my answer..

Comment: You have to mount the HDD to view its content. You can't avoid that. If you want to view it only without writing anything, you can also mount it as "read-only" as said in the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the terminal issue the following commands.

`mkdir Windows`

`sudo mount -o ro /dev/sdb1 Windows`

Note: some questions are too simple to require a long drawn out answer. My apologies if this ends up in the Low Quality Answer queue.

Comment: High-quality answer (and upvoted!)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: As pointed out by @ElderGeek, in order to make the drive mountable read/write it's unuseful to plug the HDD back into `Windows` and to just safe remove it, you'll need to remove the hibernation file as well. But since you need to only mount the filesystem read-only, refer to his post fot the correct way to do such thing.

To remove the hibernation file, you'll need to disable hibernation on the guest OS. With `Windows` booted off the HDD:

- In `Windows XP`: Click `Start` > `Control Panel` > `Power Options` > `Hybernate` tab and untick `Enable hybernation`
- In `Windows 7`/`Windows 8`: Open a command prompt as with administrative privileges and run the command `powercfg.exe -h off`

To re-enable hibernation on the guest OS:

- In `Windows XP`: Click `Start` > `Control Panel` > `Power Options` > `Hybernate` tab and tick `Enable hybernation`
- In `Windows 7`/`Windows 8`: Open a command prompt as with administrative privileges and run the command `powercfg.exe -h on`

---

On a side note: to mount a partition means to make its content available inside the `Ubuntu` filesystem, and this is required in order to access the files/folders inside it.

Comment: sorry i genuinely didn't knew what mount meant, so thank you

Comment: @MubashirA.Salam What happened? I saw you removed the acceptance mark

Comment: +1 for the side note. BTW, safely removing a drive from windows won't remove the hibernation file. Usually it has one because it was the system drive and Fast Restart was on (in Windows 8) or the system was hibernated and not fully shut down.

Comment: @ElderGeek I see, and how would someone go about removing that?

Comment: In Windows 8 you have to boot the drive back up, turn fast restart off and shut down. This disables the hibernate function. You have to so something similar with windows 7 and XP. See here: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/tr-dojo/delete-hiberfilsys-by-disabling-windows-hibernate-function/

Comment: You could expand it further with some info from the link I provided. That would make a really nice answer! Hint: `powercfg.exe` Although that might be considered off topic here as it's a Windows solution.

Comment: @ElderGeek Sure, gonna do that tommorow because now i've gotta go, i'll manage to make it AU compliant, after all in the end it's in order to solve an `Ubuntu` problem