# NTFS Drive fail to mount

Tags: 14.04, mount

I dual booted windows 8.0 x86 with ubuntu 14.04. Then tried accessing the volume containing windows but I got this error message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/van/BE96C17E96C13823: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda2" "/media/van/BE96C17E96C13823"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

I would really appreciate the solution I can take to solve this problem.

Comment: Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/596372/cant-connect-my-external-hdd-to-my-pc/596381#596381

Comment: @ElderGeek not proper solution, he must also disable hybird shutdown

Comment: @edwardtorvalds I beg to differ. Both solutions are presented as answers to that question. mounting read-only via the ro switch and disabling hybrid shutdown (fast restart). Revisit the question and **read** the answers.

Comment: @ElderGeek alright, then you must mention that this is a temporary solution and also that he will not be able to make any changes in that drive and also that he must disable hybrid shutdown to make that thing go away permanently.

Comment: @edwardtorvalds I think **read-only** is self explanatory. If you don't agree with the duplicate call, don't vote for it. Both methods in your answer are duplicates in the question I referred to. Furthermore, it's a previous question. Why duplicate the answer here? If you feel that there are answers here that aren't covered in the question I referenced flag the question for moderator attention and request a merge. That's what I do.

Comment: Actually disabling hybrid shutdown on windows in itself worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

two things can cause this problem:

1. dont start Ubuntu after you hibernate windows. Always do proper shutdown before you start Ubuntu.
2. Disable *Hybird Shutdown* in windows. [Here](http://www.maketecheasier.com/disable-hybrid-boot-and-shutdown-in-windows-8/) is how you can do that.

now all you can do is shutdown Ubuntu and start windows then follow the second method and restart and switch to Ubuntu

Hint: Please read the last sentence from the error you got:

*Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume read-only with the 'ro' mount option.*

Answer (score 0):

You ***must*** shutdown Windows completely - not just hibernate - before you try to mount it in Ubuntu.